# I know that 3 is a primitive root of $31$. How can I solve $3^b \equiv 22$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

I'm trying to solve
$$3^b \equiv 22 \mod 31$$
I know that this is of course equivalent to 
$$b \equiv L_3(2) + L_3(11) \mod 30$$
but I don't know how to solve those either. I can obviously just compute each exponent of $3$ by hand and hope to get lucky, but I'm looking for a shorter method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $22\equiv -9\pmod{31}$, so it is enough to find $L_3(9)$ and $L_3(-1)$.  For $L_3(-1)$, you can use the fact that $-1$ is the unique element of order $2$ in the multiplicative group.

Comment: Of course! Thank you!